# ReactJS - NodeJS - Issue Connecting to Graphql On AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, graphql, aws-api-gateway, apollo-client

I have a nodejs lambda function deployed on aws which exposes a lambda endpoint via API Gateway.
The endpoint is [here](https://z8zch5bp3m.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test?query=%7B%0A%09addNumbers(number1%3A1%2C%20number2%3A55)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D) and allows you to access the graphiql endpoint.

I have been trying to call this from my react code but I am getting the following error response

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

And the following console warning

```
Failed to load https://z8zch5bp3m.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have enabled cors in the API gateway but still getting this error.

My simple react code is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const ADD_NUMBERS = gql`
  query {
      addNumbers(number1:1, number2:55) {
        add
      }    
  }
`


const App = () => (
  <Query query={ADD_NUMBERS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
      if (error) return <div>Error :(</div>;

      return (
        <div>Data: {data}</div>
      )
    }}
  </Query>
)

export default App;
```

The nodejs code for my lambda function is located [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Hry3waLffFu4PBVrqOb7GbZg0WMiS6d/view?usp=sharing)

Please let me know if I need to do anything to get this lambda call working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into your code did not tell me much. I would advise you to take a look into those topics:

1. Missing Authentication Token is also returned when you make an HTTP call with the wrong method (say you want to POST, but you PUT);
2. Look into [Lambda Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html). When using Lambda Proxy Integration you can specify headers in your response. There you can make sure to allow Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Bilger_Yahov. It is on the options call where it is failing. I saw an article that mentioned setting the options call to point at a mock in order for it to pass - I tried that with no joy. I have the proxy enabled but it is not doing anything

Comment: Might be interesting to take a look here: https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-write-graphql-apps-using-aws-lambda/

Comment: Thanks @Bilger_Yahov - will go through this to see if its of any assistance

Comment: Actually - I followed that tutorial to create my graphql endpoint in Lambda. What they have described is working but the cors between my application and API gateway is now

Answer (score 1):

Got this working by recreating my api gateway endpoints with cors enabled from the start and it worked as expected